# Бесконечный цикл

Tags: c

Взял код из Керниган Ритчи Язык программирования Си:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
long nc;
nc=0;
while (getchar()!=EOF)
    ++nc;
printf("%1d\n", nc);
}
```

Получается бесконечный цикл, причем управление на  `printf("%1d\n", nc);` не передается. Я уже пробовал вместо EOF и разные символы, и разные цифры, но все равно управление остается в цикле.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @belosks, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Ввести EOF с клавиатуры -- это нажать Ctrl-D в *nix или Ctrl-Z в винде.
(и в формате `printf` у Вас скорее всего ошибка -- вместо `1` наверное подразумевалась буква `l` (читайте внимательно `man 3 printf`))

Comment: добавлю: EOF расшифровывается как End Of File, символ конца файла. Если правильно помню, то он занимает больше байта, и getchar из-за такого рода символов возвращает не char, a int. Соответственно такой цикл ждет *окончания файла*, как его сэмулировать в stdin - написано выше.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((c = getchar())  !=EOF) {


}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565663/while-c-getchar-eof-not-terminating

Comment: @WorldCount, на выполнение условия это никак не повлияет

Comment: повлияет, если c типа unsigned char, - цикл действительно станет бесконечным